# Move table row from one table to another - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a question about `ng-repeat` and to move data from one table to another. Basically i have one table that is `"master"` and shows all the data from API request, after i populate it in a table i have a button on each row that works like `"favorite-this-row"`. After a user click on `"favorite-this-row"` i want it to move the row to another table called `"favorite-table"` and show the data here.

**This is my "Master"-table:** (i wont paste whole table just the needy parts)

```
<md-card flex="45" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-xs="100" 
    ng-show="(account|filter:searchName).length > 0"
    ng-repeat="account in containers | groupBy: 'accountId'  | toArray | filter:searchName track by $index ">

        ... Bunch of HTML code down......

    **//Favorite button**

<md-button ng-init="item.isfavorite = false;"
       ng-class="{yellow : item.isfavorite}"
       ng-click="item.isfavorite =!item.isfavorite; AddFavorite(item.isfavorite,container.containerId)"
       class="md-icon-button md-accent md-warn" aria-label="Favorite">      
<ng-md-icon icon="favorite" ng-init="item.isfavorite = false;"></ng-md-icon>
</md-button>

<p ng-if="item.isfavorite">Remove from favorites - {{item.isfavorite}} </p>
<p ng-if="!item.isfavorite">Add to favorite</p>
```

**Now this is my "Favorite"-table:**

```
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in containers" ng-show="item.isfavorite">
         <td>s{{ x.containerId }}</td>
         <td>s{{ x.accountId }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When i click on the button `<md-button ng-init="item.isfavorite = false;" ....>` i want it to slice and move to my favorite table that just repeats `containerId` and `accountId`. as you can see ive added `ng-show="item.isfavorite"` but it does not work/show.

`AddFavorite(item.isfavorite,container.containerId)"` is just a `console.log` in controller.

Hope someone could help me, thanks!

Comment: First of all you shouldn't have `ng-init="item.isfavorite = false;"` as it should be by default or if it's not I would suggest you to initialize it in controller rather than DOM. Also seems like you are looping through `account in containers` so you would have `account` instead of `item`.

Comment: so i should change all item.isfavorite to container.isfavorite and also remove ng-init? But why does it not show in "favorite" table. ng-repeat is containers not account

Comment: Changing `item.isfavorite` to `account.isfavorite` should be enough to fix your issue. It does show in favorite because you are repeating `x` through `containers` and using same `x` to show child properties while in masters table you are repeating `account` through `containers` but you are using `item` which by your provided code does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @avius said it should be `account` instead of item also in favirote table it should be `x` instead of `item` something like

```
<md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="account.isfavorite =!account.isfavorite">Button</md-button>

<p ng-if="account.isfavorite">Remove from favorites - {{account.isfavorite}} </p>
<p ng-if="!account.isfavorite">Add to favorite</p>



 <tr ng-repeat="x in containers" ng-show="x.isfavorite">
```

[Check this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pO6FrN28QI98Ch6xHqFK?p=preview)

Comment: Awsome, i changed to "account.isfavorite" and ng-repeat="x.isfavorite" and it worked :)